# SelectList default value

Tags: c#, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I have a drop down list in my project, with this code providing the lists values

`CrawlIntervalList = new SelectList(new[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, 2);`

i am trying to set a default value of `2`. Am i right in thinking this is the default value ^, if it is it doesnt seem to be working, if not, what does this value mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `SelectList` is not generic, so it uses `object` as item type. When you pass an `int` to a method expecting an `object`, that `int` is automatically boxed. That boxing operation wraps the value of that `int` in a new `object` and puts it on the heap. This boxing operation occurs again every time you assign a value type (like `int`) to a variable of type `object`, or if you try to pass a value type to a method expecting an `int`.

The second parameter seems to be the default value, but the `2` you pass is being **boxed**, which creates a new instance of `object`. At the same time, the numbers in your array are being boxed, too (`IEnumerable` works with `object`, too). These two boxing operations occur separately though, and the `2` in your array and the `2` that you passed as second parameter end up as different `object`s on different locations on the heap. Thus, the `SelectList` has no way of finding out that these two `2`s are meant to refer to the same object.

The solution is to let this boxing operation happen only once.

You can get around this by either selecting the default element manually, or using an `object[]`:

```
object[] values = new object[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
CrawlIntervalList = new SelectList(values, values[1]);
```

Not that, by creating an `object[]`, all integers in it are being boxed to `object`, thus creating references. By passing `values[1]` as the second parameter, you make sure that the correct reference is passed to the constructor.

More info on Boxing here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx